# How to store "\0" in C++ char array?

Tags: c++, arrays

According to the C++ char array rules it ends with \0 null character. If i want to save and print `\0` in C++ char array how to do it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char name[] = {'H', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'a', '\0'};
    cout << name; // how to print Honda\0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're asking because my understanding of the solution is so simple: `char name[] = { 'H', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'a', '\\', '0', '\0' };`

Comment: that's fine. working well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape characters have to be escaped

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char name[] = {'H', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'a', '\\', '0', '\0'};
                                         // ^^^^^^^^^^
    cout << name; // prints Honda\0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also just do `"Honda\\0"`

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the questioner means.  See my answew.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store `'\\'` and a `'0'`, as well as a `'\0'` at the end to terminate it. The `'\\'` has two backslashes because one of them is the escape character.

Answer (score 2):

> According to the C++ char array rules it ends with \0 null character.

There is no rule saying that char *arrays* end with null character in general. However, it is true that character *strings* must end so, and that character arrays passed to a stream must be character strings.

> If i want to save and print \0 in C++ char array how to do it

You cannot do so as part of a character string.

But, you can print it individually, as a standalone character:

```
char nul = '\0'
std::cout << nul;
```

However, if you expect to see something in a terminal, then you may be disappointed because `\0` is a non printable character. If you pipe the program output to `hexdump` or similar tool, then you can see that the null character (i.e. value zero) is part of the output of the program.

If your goal is instead to print the characters `\` and `0`, simply make those characters part of the string (as already shown in other answers, but I'll include it here for completeness). Remember that the escape character must be escaped.

```
char name[] = {'H', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'a', '\\', '0' '\0'};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by `'\0'` the **single** terminating character at the end of a C string, you don't have to store it explicitly as the other answers have explained.  Note that storing extra `'\'` and `'0'` printable characters before the terminating `'\0'` **single** character is not the same as printing/storing the terminating `'\0'`.

You can't print the terminating `'\0'` value of a C string using `[f]printf( "%s", ... );`  Per the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **7.21.6.1  The `fprintf` function**

> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer
>   to the initial element  of  an  array  of  character  type.
>   **Characters  from  the  array  are written  up  to  (but  not  including)  the  terminating  null  character.**   If  the precision 
>   is  specified,  no  more  than  that  many  bytes  are  written.   If 
>   the precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the
>   array, the array shall contain a null character.

You can't print the actual `'\0'` character itself, as it's non-printing, but you can print a string to represent it:

```
void printStrAndTerm( FILE *fp, const unsigned char *str )
{
    do
    {
        if ( *str )
        {
            fputc( *str, fp );
        }
        else
        {
            fputs( "\\0", fp );
        }
        str++;
    }
    while ( *str );
}
```